# how to avoid Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the below module export in my javascript file, so that I can access it from node.js based build setup (grunt, require..).

```
    ....
if(module && module.exports) {
        module.exports = m;
    }
```

when I use the same file in browser, it gives error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined const.js:49
(anonymous function)
```

I **do not** use node as backend.
how can I avoid this error? That is, I need to export `m` so that `require` it during build (node based), but works standalone in browser.

why doesn't the browser treat the variable module as undefined and not throw any error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Test `typeof module !== "undefined"` instead of `module`

> why doesn't the browser treat the variable module as undefined and not throw any error?

Because, as well as being undefined, it is also *undeclared*. This is an excellent feature for throwing an error when you make a typo in a variable name. For example, it is better for the following to error instead of being treated as false:

```
var loose = true;
if (lose) {
}
```